# how can i get data items present inside a tree view using white framework

Tags: ui-testing, white-framework

I have 5 dataitems in a in a tabular format inside a tree .I want to navigate a particular filed of each data items.

1)  Tree
a)  Data item1
b)  Data item2
c)  Data item 3
d)  Data item5

Id  Name    No  Tag Adc location
1   xyz 12  34rt    2w  kdc
4   Hjk 67  56tr    7y  jk
5   Hg  87  7h  Lk  Kl
6   Kl  90  8u  Jk  io
I want to get the “Tag ” filed  values of each data items.

The UI spy is showing like tree and the data items.
Tree
Data item1
Data item2
Data item 3
Data item5

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can access the Tag property of your data items using White because it is not an automation property but what you can do is defining your test value in the property HelpText of your data items.

```
...
myTreeViewItem.SetValue(AutomationProperties.HelpText, "MyValueForAutomation");
...
```

Then in your automation code, you can retrieve it like this

```
Application application = Application.Attach("WpfTestApplication1");
var window = application.GetWindow("MainWindow");
var yourTree = window.Get<Tree>("MyTestTree");

var treeRoot = yourTree.Nodes.FirstOrDefault();
treeRoot.Select();
treeRoot.Expand();

foreach (TreeNode node in treeRoot.Nodes)
{
    object help = node.AutomationElement.GetCurrentPropertyValue(AutomationElement.HelpTextProperty, true);
    if(help != AutomationElement.NotSupported)
    {
        string helpText = (string)help;
    } 
}
```